# How to use Windows authentication credentials to schedule Crystal Reports in SAP BO CMC

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

Hi I am new to SAP BusinessObjects Central Management Console and trying to schedule a Crystal Report. For this I made an ODBC connection to a database (NCBODS) in the Server machine using Windows authentication. I also gave same windows credentials in CMC as shown in below image. But It gives me an error saying:

> Error in File `C:\Program Files\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 11.5\Data\procSched\SDDVCTRTRCH11.reportjobserver\~tmp5448125TH7b9b16.rpt`: Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 18456 ]`

I have given the same Windows credentials that I use to connect to the app server. Still I am getting:

> Incorrect log on parameters.

But when I use a SQL Authenticated Login in the ODBC connection and also use the same SQL Login credentials in CMC it works fine.

So the problem here is when I use the Windows credentials it throws error but works fine when SQL credentials are used. Is there any way I can use Windows credentials in CMC? I really appreciate if any one can help me on this.

[image]

Comment: This is just a suggestion and not the answer to your question.......Problem here I see is BO CMC is accessing the database so it is looking for database credentials...

You have created `ODBC` connection in server and you gave windows credentials.. First thing you need to look is...have you tested the connection in ODBC after the making connection.. and is the connection successful with `windows credentials`?

If the `connection is successful` with windows credentials in ODBC then you shouldn't get any issue with BO CMC else you need to rectify that first then proceed to Report scheduling..

Answer (score 0):

If you create an ODBC DSN with authentication set to trusted connection (Windows authentication), be aware that a different account will be used when creating the DSN and when using it in BusinessObjects:

- When *creating* the connection: the DSN is created using the credentials you're logged on with (i.e. your Windows AD user account)
- When *running* a report: the connection to the database is initiated through BusinessObjects, thus the account which BusinessObjects is running with, will be used to connect to the database.

In other words, you need to make sure that following requirements are met:

1. Your SIA (Server Intelligence Agent) which runs your CMS, Crystal Reports servers, etc must be configured to run with an Active Directory service account. By default, it runs with the *Local System Account*, which will not be able to log on to your database (as it's a local account, it's not even able to access network resources).
2. You need to grant the service account you used to configure the SIA in step 1 the necessary rights to your database.

**Remarks:**

1. If you're using AD SSO, you cannot schedule the report so that it uses the Active Directory credentials of a certain user (because BOBJ doesn't store these credentials, it only verifies them at logon).
2. If you're not using AD SSO, but are authenticating users to the BusinessObjects platform (InfoView) with manual AD authentication, you can set the option *Synchronization of Credentials*. This forces BOBJ to store the AD credentials when the user authenticates.

[image: Synchronization of Credentials]

The credentials are stored in the user profile (*Database Credentials*).

[image: Database Credentials]